# Multi-touch gestures in GNOME 3.14

Tags: gnome3, live-usb, wayland, multi-touch

I'm trying out the [GNOME 3.14 live ISO](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/misc/promo-usb/gnome-3.14.iso) and I would like to test multi touch gestures as well as Wayland session.

The [promotional video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7p8Prlu3owc) shows multitouch gestures to zoom in and out, show the overwiev, switch workspaces etc. I've tried them but nothing seems to work on my trackpad (CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad).

Also I cannot see a wayland session from the login page.

Is that possible to test any (or both)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i can tell, the gestures support in Gnome 3.14 are limited to touch-screen devices such as tablets, touch-enabled laptops, etc. According to the developers, gesture support for touchpads and trackers will be added in the next version (Gnome 3.16). Relevant links:

https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.14/

https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/Gestures

It is difficult to enter a wayland session from the live ISO image as the `gnome-session-wayland-session` package is not present in the live image. This has to be installed after which you will have to restart `gdm` with the session set as `gnome-wayland`. Detailed instructions are provided [in this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/LinuxActionShow/comments/2evjwm/test_gnome_314_beta_1_on_wayland_without/).

Comment: Thank'you very much. I'm gonna try it tomorrow morning and give a feedback

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Fisrt I had to use yum instead of dnf. Then starting gnome-session manually did not work. So I used sudo systemctl start gem, log in, created a new user with password. Got back to gdm login screen, selected the new user and selected "Gnome on Wayland". But unfortunately, after entering the password it goes back to GDM login page again.

Comment: That sounds weird... I haven't actually tried it out myself. Have you checked driver compatibility? Only the open-source drivers currently support Wayland. If it still persists, i guess a better option would be to actually install Gnome 3.14 on a system and check it out... :(

Comment: I've and intel video card (Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)) that should work with the open source driver...

Comment: Just to be sure, did you follow these exact steps:
1. Boot from Live CD. 2. `Ctrl+Alt+F2` 3. `sudo systemctl stop gdm` 4. `sudo yum install gnome-session-wayland-session` 5. `gnome-session --session=gnome-wayland` 
Nothing more and nothing less? For each boot of the live cd, you will have to re-install `gnome-session-wayland-session`. Let me know how it pans out...

Comment: Yes, just like that! on 'gnome-session --session=gnome-wayland' nothing happens neither by manually going to Ctrl+Alt+F1

Comment: Can't think of anything else to do... Only suggestion other than trying to install it to your machine is to try out Rebecca Black OS which states that it uses Wayland as default.

Comment: I finally got it! I used the Fedora 21 Beta live iso and followed the instructions. I had to run a system update first. BTW, wayland session looks smoother but it is still very buggy. Sometimes, just closing a window causes gnome-session to crash

Comment: Good to know. Yeah wayland will make the whole Linux desktop experience a lot smoother but it is still under development. I think you can expect slightly more stability when Fedora 21 releases. But production use is only advised after Gnome 3.16 relases.

Comment: As long as it is installed, you should be bale to select Wayland from the GDM login screen ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Mu5VQ1M.png)) - however it does not work in VirtualBox (with Guest Additions - probably due to the VM drivers being for X :(