# Deactivate the new native gesture support in GNOME 3.14

Tags: configuration, gnome3, touch-screen, multi-touch

The new version 3.14 of the GNOME desktop now supports multitouch gestures natively. (see e.g. [Multi-touch gestures in GNOME 3.14](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158407/multi-touch-gestures-in-gnome-3-14))

How can I deactivate this feature?

I would like to continue using my touchegg setup, where I can customize and assign gestures in any way I like. But touchegg can no longer subscribe to the gestures on the root window if gnome-panel already did so.